# Space Complexity of an initialised pointer data structure

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers, space-complexity

I have got a question.

In terms of theoretical computer science, when we analyse an algorithm, if an algorithm initialises a new data structure, then we consider that data structure as part of space complexity.

Now I am not too sure about this part then.

Let's say I have got an array of `int` and I would like to map them by using a map of `int` pointers. Such as

```
std::map<int*,int*> mymap;
for (int i = 1; i < arraySize; i++) {
   mymap[&arr[i-1]]=&arr[i];
}
```

If this algorithm was not using pointers, then we could clearly state that it is initialising a map with size of n, hence space complexity is O(n), however for this case, where we are using pointers, what would be the space complexity of this algorithm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The space complexity of a single pointer is the same as that of any other primitive - i.e. `O(1)`.

`std::map<K,V>` is implemented as a tree of `N` nodes. Its space complexity is `O(N*space-complexity-of-one-node)`, so the total space complexity in your case is `O(N)`.

Note that the big-O notation factors out the constant multiplier: although the big-O space complexity of an `std::map<Ptr1,Ptr2>` and `std::vector<Ptr1>` is the same, the multiplier for the map is higher, because tree construction imposes its overhead for storing tree nodes and connections among them.

Comment: I think I got it.
I was thinking in a way that we are not initialising a new variable at stack level, however assigning pointers take space in heap. So we also consider that one, right?

Comment: @SarpKaya Correct, space complexity takes heap, stack, and static memory in consideration.